# How to execute command "./gradlew clean build" before docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

to wrote Code

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  moinda-db:
    container_name: moinda-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: moinda
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: moinda
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: moinda
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - moinda-local

  moinda-app:
    container_name: moinda-app
    build:
      context: ../moinda-api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - moinda-db
    networks:
      - moinda-local

networks:
  moinda-local:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/moinda-api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} moinda.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/moinda.jar"]
```

as with Title, I want to be executing command "./gradlew clean build" before build images

command syntax is not friendly yet..
try to right down command In "Dockerfile"

```
1. 
RUN ["./gradlew", "clean", "build"]

2.
CMD ["./gradlew", "clean", "build"]
```

First Command is execute but failed

Second Command is not execute..

plz write comment,,

Comment: Your current Dockerfile doesn't build the jar file, it assumes the build has been run on the host before anything happens in Docker space.  The Dockerfile can't cause that command to be run on the host.  You could `COPY` the entire source tree in and then build it, but it'd be a substantially larger Dockerfile than what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script file and do something like this:

```bash
./gradlew clean build
docker-compose up
```

Comment: [@DarkDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8106685/darkdeveloper) 
Can't I write it in a file and run it..?

Comment: @awse2050 yes exactly. create a file named `deploy.sh` and put these lines in it. then give it run privilege `sudo chmod +x deploy.sh`. put the file in the project directory and run it with './deploy.sh' command